# How can I make a namespace for Laravel controller?

Tags: laravel-4, controller, namespaces

I'm trying to make controller SecondController with namespace Admin to be Admin\SecondController

this controller should be saved in "controllers\admin" folder with lowercase (a)

when trying to generate controller using

```
artisan controller:make "Admin\SecondController"
```

it save the controller in folder Admin with upper case (A)

so the controller doesn't work as i use it in route namespace

is there any way to make controller SecondController with uppercase "A" namespace "Admin" and put that file inside  lowercase "a" folder "controllers\admin" with lowercase ?